# Meteor Accounts-facebook etc for React instead of BlazeJS

Tags: facebook, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

Does anyone know if there is a way to create facebook login/sign up flow using the meteor accounts library, for ReactJS instead of BlazeJS?

All the versions I've seen on the web are based on BlazeJS. They all require some HTML file. Which breaks the current convention for ReactJS. Any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way forward is to write your own React UI and use methods like `Accounts.createUser` etc. to do the auth and other stuff.

A straightforward way is to use studiointeracts's package - [accounts-ui](https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui)